# AS3 - Unable to add children when exporting in Frame 2 for classes?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Here is my code:

```
public function main() {

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, hurdlesReactToArrowKeys);
        var loginScreen:dealerLogin = new dealerLogin
        addChild(loginScreen)
```

My classes are set to be exported on Frame 2 and on Frame 1 of the SWF on the timeline there is a pre-loader.

Nothing appears on the stage. If it is set to export in Frame 1, it appears after 60% preload on Frame 1.

Why would this not work? What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that in your Document Class? The Document Class gets exported on frame 1 no matter what.
So it is probably running that code before the DealerLogin class is loaded.

There are a couple of ways around that. My preferred solution is to not use a Document Class. Instead, I link the Main class to an empty MovieClip and put that on the timeline on frame 3 (after all the classes are exported). This way I know everything has finished loading before any part of the app starts running.